# How it works super() and super. in Java

Tags: java

I have this doubt and I found information in this forum but I don't understand exactly how it the differences between super() an super.

Could anyone explain this ?

```
***Parent class***

    public class Bread {
        public int variable1;
        private int numero2;
        protected int numero3;

        public Bread() {

        }
    }


 public class Bread2 extends Bread{
        public Bread2() {
         super();
        }
}

/**There are differents examples***/

public class Bread2 extends Bread{
    public Bread2(int id) {
        super.numero3 = 8;
        super.variable1 = 6;
    }
```

Comment: This is covered by **any** basic inheritance tutorial. [This one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. super() is used to invoke immediate parent class constructor.
2. super is used to refer immediate parent class instance variable.

For more on super go through this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)